# LinPhone building process for Android

Tags: android-ndk

I am building Linphone application for android. I am working in Ubuntu 11.04 OS.

I Followed the steps given in README file:

1. Download the Android ndk (>=r5c) from google.
2. Install the autotools: autoconf, automake, aclocal, libtoolize pkgconfig
3. Run the ./prepare_sources.sh script in the top level directory. This will download iLBC source files and convert some assembly files in VP8 project.
   `$ ./prepare_sources.sh`
4. Finally from directory linphone-android, just execute command:
   `$ ${my google ndk directory}/ndk-build`

I got the output in terminal as

```
StaticLibrary  : libopencoreamr.a 
Compile arm    : vpx <= vpx_mem.c 
In file included from jni/..//submodules/externals/build/libvpx/../../libvpx/vpx_mem/vpx_mem.c:18: 

jni/..//submodules/externals/build/libvpx/../../libvpx/vpx_mem/include/vpx_mem_intrnl.h:14:24: error: vpx_config.h: No such file or directory 
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/vpx/vpx_mem/vpx_mem.o] Error 1
```

If i solve this error i will be able to  compile and run the Linphone application. Some one please help me to solve this..

Comment: PLease use locate command to locate vpx_config.h . I am having the same problem and I am unbale to locate this file in repository.

Comment: Hi, is there some particular reason that you did not accept an answer yet?

Comment: check complete guide on http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Open terminal
2. Download source code through command: git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git --recursive
3. Go to root directory of the downloaded project through command: cd /home/your_downloaded_project_path/
4. Fire the command: ./prepare_sources.sh /home/android-ndk-r7b/
5. Go to root directory of NDK folder through command: cd /home/android-ndk-r7b/
6. Fire the command: export NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/home/your_downloaded_project_path/
7. ./ndk_build clean
8. ./ndk_build -i

Note: Here /home/android-ndk-r7b/ will be your NDK path where you have stored downloaded NDK

Try dis..if still not work mention error what you would get.

Comment: after we build it.. how will we import this project into eclipse plz help posted my query here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826876/linphone-android-how-to-import-the-library-project

Comment: Hi, Bhavana. I am new to Linphone compilation. Is there any document how to download latest and compile linphone ? Please provide me a link. Thanks

Comment: @GangadharNimbally please follow this link http://www.linphone.org/eng/documentation/guide/getting-started-with-linphone-for-androidiphone.html

Comment: ./prepare_sources.sh: No such file or directory show when i use in ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the complete path the ndk when executing prepare_sources

```
$./prepare_sources.sh /complete/path/to/android-ndk
```

If you only specify the relative path to the ndk, it'll also throw the same error.

Then, you can call 'ndk-build', 'ant debug',... whatever you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Also a key issue appears to be that you must be using version 7 of the NDK as well

Answer (score 0):

Check the output from prepare_sources.sh carefully for errors. Errors during this phase can lead to the error that you describe.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need an answer...

In your ubuntu 11.04, open your terminal, make sure you are the root user

```
* make sure you have done this: "git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git --recursive" //*the --recursive part is very important
* then do this: apt-get install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config
* go to your project root: cd/home/user/project //wherver your project is
* in your project root: export PATH=/home/user/android-ndk:$PATH //wherever your android-ndk is stored in
* then run ./prepare_sources.sh //in your project root still
* after that do this: /home/user/android-ndk/ndk-build // in your project root too
```

Comment: Oic. I have not come across this problem yet. But have you tried cleaning and refreshing the project?

Comment: Thanks winona, I got it compiled and I am able to run it now. But its unable to launch the screen. Debugger shows the error in LinphoneManager.class, in createAndStart method.

Comment: Maybe you check the method in the class? Try to clean and refresh the project?

Comment: Try right-clicking on your project > android tools > fix project properties. if worse comes to worse, get the source code from start all over again?

Comment: @Winona... any idea about this buddy??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251081/linphone-compile-on-windows-8