# Linphone Compile on Windows 8

Tags: android

I am building Linphone application for android. I am working in Windows 8 64-Bit OS

I Followed the steps given in README file:

```
Download the Android ndk (>=r5c) from google.
Install the autotools: autoconf, automake, aclocal, libtoolize pkgconfig

Run the ./prepare_sources.sh script in the top level directory. This will download iLBC source files and convert some assembly files in VP8 project.
$ ./prepare_sources.sh

Finally from directory linphone-android, just execute command:
$ ${my google ndk directory}/ndk-build
```

then i get following error in Cygwin terminal:

> $ ./prepare_sources.sh
>   ./prepare_sources.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
>   ./prepare_sources.sh: line 3: C:UsersNomsDesktoplinphone-android: command not found
>   ./prepare_sources.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
>   ./prepare_sources.sh: line 29: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
>   ./prepare_sources.sh: line 29:`cd $topdir/submodules/libilbc-rfc3951 && ./autog'n.sh && ./configure && make || ( echo "iLBC prepare stage failed" ; exit 1 )

Comment: Do you have cygwin installed and configured on your PC?

Comment: @323go.. yes i had installed cygwin and autotools.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [mingw](http://www.mingw.org) to compile it. I've built the library successfully. But not yet apk, cause some build error in myeclipse...

Comment: I have installed.. now how to compile??