# Linphone NDK compilation error

Tags: android, android-ndk, sip, linphone

Getting error when trying to compile Linphone Native Library using NDK

```
G:\WorkSpaces\Demo\LinphoneLauncherActivity>G:\android-ndk-r8d-windows\android-n
dk-r8d\ndk-build

Build X264 plugin for mediastreamer2

"Compile arm  : vpx <= vpx_mem.c

In file included from jni/..//submodules/externals/build/libvpx/../../libvpx/vpx
_mem/vpx_mem.c:18:0:

jni/..//submodules/externals/build/libvpx/../../libvpx/vpx_mem/include/vpx_mem_i
ntrnl.h:14:24: fatal error: vpx_config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/vpx/vpx_mem/vpx_mem.o] Error 1
```

Any solution or help regarding this is thankful.. Please help if anybody knows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LinPhone building process for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407496/linphone-building-process-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the linphone instructions,  or at least run the `prepare_sources.sh` script.